# Suppress OPTIONS Requests in Angular CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors

If I have foreknowledge that CORS calls made with Angular will, indeed, work, can I suppress the OPTIONS calls so that they don't continue needlessly occurring in production?

Comment: The OPTIONS calls are part of CORS. If you want to not have them, then I would suggest using your webserver as a reverse proxy to your backend, then the client app will not even need to make CORS requests.

Comment: Need any further info adding to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This OPTIONS request tells the client if a CORS request will be allowed; and, for those requests, which methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) can be executed.

[According to W3c options call is not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction) if you are implementing only [simple methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-method): GET/POST/HEAD.

So where you set your Access-Control-Allow-Methods if it is * try changing it to "GET,POST" and based on the standard (if the browser follows), your browser doesn't need to fire the options call.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `OPTIONS` request you need to make sure that your request is a "[simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control)" request.

> A simple cross-site request is one that:
>
> - Only uses `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST`. If `POST` is used to send data to the server, the `Content-Type` of the data sent to the server with the HTTP `POST` request is one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.
> - Does not set custom headers with the HTTP Request (such as `X-Modified`, etc.)

Check that Angular isn't setting `x-requested-with` or anything else unexpected.